# authenticate google API without a config file

Tags: python, google-api, google-bigquery, google-api-client

I am trying to authenticate google API without a config file, I can't even find proof it is possible other than old code in my service that wasn't used in years.

My class receive this dict:

```
   self._connection_data = {
        "type": args,
        "project_id": args,
        "private_key_id": args,
        "private_key": args,
        "client_email": args,
        "client_id": args,
        "auth_uri": args,
        "token_uri": args,
        "auth_provider_x509_cert_url": args,
        "client_x509_cert_url": args
    }
```

and the code is -

```
   from google.cloud import bigquery
   from google.oauth2 import service_account

   def _get_client(self):

        credentials = service_account.Credentials.from_service_account_info(self._connection_data)
        return bigquery.Client(project=self._project_id, credentials=credentials, location='US')
```

I receive the error

```
'{"error":"invalid_grant","error_description":"Invalid grant: account not found"}
```

however, everything works when I use a helper file for the configs called config.json and an OS environmentnt variable:

```
os.environ['GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS'] = "config.json"
self.job_config = bigquery.QueryJobConfig()
self.job_config.use_legacy_sql = True

return bigquery.Client()
```

I don't want a solution with the env variable, I would like to use the Credentials class without a file path

Comment: I think you also need to pass in an instance of `requests.Session` via the `_http` keyword object when using the `from_service_account_info` method. See https://github.com/googleapis/python-bigquery/blob/master/google/cloud/bigquery/client.py#L132

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well In the end I managed to make my code work without any need for the global variable or a file path. I had a problem with my configured credentials...

This is the code -

```
# init class here
    self.job_config = bigquery.QueryJobConfig()
    self.job_config.use_legacy_sql = True

def _get_client(self):
    credentials = service_account.Credentials.from_service_account_info(self._connection_data)
    return bigquery.Client(project=self._project_id, credentials=credentials)

 # function to get columns 
        query_job = self._get_client().query(query, job_config=self.job_config)
        results = query_job.result(timeout=self._current_timeout)
```

The only part I was missing was to send the QueryJobConfig class with legacy SQL set to true in all of my queries.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, there are no other methods to authenticate your API request without either using an environment variable or specifying the key file path. There are some ways of authenticating your request with GCP using a key json file. Before anything, you should set up your service account and download the json file with your key, as described [here](https://cloud.google.com/docs/authentication/production#creating_a_service_account).

Then, the first method is using default credentials, according to the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/authentication/getting-started#application_default_credentials):

> If you don't specify credentials when constructing the client, the
>    client library will look for credentials in the environment.

That means, you just need to set your environment variable. Then, the Google Client Library will determine the credentials implicitly. In addition, it also allows you to provide credentials separately from your application, which eases the process of making changes in the code. You can set the environment variable as follows:

```
export GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS="/home/user/Downloads/[FILE_NAME].json"
```

After setting it, you would be able to run the following [code](https://cloud.google.com/docs/authentication/getting-started#verifying_authentication):

```
def implicit():
    from google.cloud import storage

    # If you don't specify credentials when constructing the client, the
    # client library will look for credentials in the environment.
    storage_client = storage.Client()

    # Make an authenticated API request
    buckets = list(storage_client.list_buckets())
    print(buckets)
```

Secondly, you can specify the file path within your code using the `[google.oauth2.service_account][3]` module. It is stated in the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/docs/authentication#authentication_strategies) that:

> An OAuth 2.0 client identifies the application and lets end users
>   authenticate your application with Google. It allows your application
>   to access Google Cloud APIs on behalf of the end user.

In order to use the module, you can use one of both codes:

```
#It creates credentials using your .json file and the Credentials.from_service_account_file constructor
credentials = service_account.Credentials.from_service_account_file(
    'service-account.json')
```

Or

```
#If you set the environment variable, you can also use
#info = json.loads(os.environ['GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS_JSON_STRING'])
#Otherwise, you specify the path inside json.load() as below
service_account_info = json.load(open('service_account.json'))
credentials = service_account.Credentials.from_service_account_info(
    service_account_info)
```

Finally, I encourage you to check the Authentication strategies in the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/docs/authentication#authentication_strategies).